# Killing form over finite fields

Tags: lie-algebras, finite-fields, bilinear-form

For a Lie algebra $\mathcal{sl}(n, \mathbb{C})$, it is well known that the Killing form $\kappa(A,B) = 2n tr(AB)$ for all $A, B \in \mathcal{sl}(n, \mathbb{C})$.

Now let $F=\mathbb{F}_p$ be a finite field. Is there any relation, like above, between the Killing form $\kappa$ and the trace $tr$ over $\mathcal{sl}(n, \mathbb{F}_p)$? Perhaps we can conclude if $tr(AB) = 0$, then $\kappa(A,B) = 0$.

Comment: Why would the Killing form be different over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: @user420261 Because it is zero for $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ with $p\mid n$, which is really not the case over fields of characteristic zero.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sure, but it's still $2n \mathrm{tr}(AB)$

Comment: @user420261 By definition $\kappa(A,B):= tr(adA.adB)$, is it still $\kappa(A, B) = 2ntr(AB)$ over $\mathcal{sl}(n, \mathbb{F}_p)$?If so, could you please tell me how we prove?

Answer (score 1):

In general we do not have $\kappa(A,B)=0$ because of $tr(AB)=0$. For example, the trace form for $\mathfrak{sl}_p(\mathbb{F}_p)$ for $p>2$ is non-degenerate, but nevertheless the Killing form is identically zero. So in general it is not true that the Killing form of a simple modular Lie algebra is a non-zero multiple of the trace form. 
 For the Lie algebra $\mathbb{sl}_n(K)$ we have
$$
\kappa(x,y)=2n\cdot tr(xy)
$$
over an arbitrary field $K$. This follows from a direct computation using a basis of $\mathbb{gl}_n(K)$, which gives $\kappa(x,y)=2n tr(xy)-2tr(x)tr(y)$ on this basis. Since $\mathbb{sl}_n(K)$ is an ideal, we obtain $\kappa(x,y)=2n\cdot tr(xy)$ as the restriction for trace zero matrices.

Comment: Why is the Killing form for $\mathbb{sl}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ identically zero? I thought it is $diag\{ 8, -8, 8 \}$ if we use a basis $X = E_{12} + E_{21}, Y = -E_{12}+E_{21}$ and $Z = E_{11} - E_{22}$. Since $p > 2$, $8$ is a unit. Moreover, the statement you described, you also meant it is true for over a finite field, right? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo. The Killing form is zero for $p\mid n$.